# Display sum of Counter over time period in a Grafana table view

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Let's say I have a Counter – named `requests` - representing the number of requests my server handles. It has a label named `customer` indicating which customer made the request.

I want to know "How many requests were made over the past 24 hours, per customer" and I've figured out I can get this from Prometheus by querying:

```
sum by (customer) (sum_over_time(requests[1d]))
```

Which gives me a moderately readable table that looks like:

```
{customer="Googley"}          | 123
{customer="ApplesAndOranges"} | 256
```

The problem comes up when I try to get this same table view in Grafana. I'm creating a new Table on a Dashboard, and I plug in the same query from above. But Grafana gives me a time-based display instead of a summary! And it includes at the bottom of the table a selector to choose which customer to show the time series data for.

[image]

How can I convince Grafana to show me the summary numbers for the whole time period in a table, similar to how Prometheus does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You whole attempt has a couple flaws:

1. If your metric is actually a counter, your query should be `sum by (customer) (increase(requests[1d]))`.
2. In Grafana [`$__interval`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__interval) stand for time corresponding to one "column" on time scale. Based on your description, you probably intended to use [`$__range`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__range) instead.
3. To get only last result of the query, and represented as actual table data, and not independent time series, you need to change options *Format* to **Table**, and *Type* to **Instant**. Those options can be seen underneath the query in your screenshot.

To hide column *Time*, you can use Transformation [*Organize field*](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#organize-fields)

Comment: WOW thank you so much. ❤️ That was exactly what I needed to know, on all three points! It looks like it's working exactly as I intended now. Thank you!